# How to do named entity recognition (NER) using quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

Having a dataframe with text

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,2), text = c("My best friend John works and Google", "However he would like to work at Amazon as he likes to use python and stay at Canada")
```

Without any preprocessing

How is it possible to extract name entity recognition like [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da)

Example results words

```
dfresults = data.frame(id=c(1,2), ner_words = c("John, Google", "Amazon, python, Canada")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this without **quanteda**, using the **spacyr** package -- a wrapper around the spaCy library mentioned in your linked article.

Here, I have slightly edited your input data.frame.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), 
                 text = c("My best friend John works at Google.", 
                          "However he would like to work at Amazon as he likes to use Python and stay in Canada."),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then:

```r
library("spacyr")
library("dplyr")

# -- need to do these before the next function will work:
# spacy_install()
# spacy_download_langmodel(model = "en_core_web_lg")

spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_lg")
#> Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
#> successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.0.10, language model: en_core_web_lg)
#> (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")

txt <- df$text
names(txt) <- df$id

spacy_parse(txt, lemma = FALSE, entity = TRUE) %>%
    entity_extract() %>%
    group_by(doc_id) %>%
    summarize(ner_words = paste(entity, collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   doc_id ner_words             
#>   <chr>  <chr>                 
#> 1 1      John, Google          
#> 2 2      Amazon, Python, Canada
```

Comment: If I receive error like this `Finding a python executable with spaCy installed...
Error in set_spacy_python_option(python_executable, virtualenv, condaenv,  : 
  spaCy or language model en is not installed in any of python executables.` how can I resolve it?

Comment: See the spacyr installation instructions at https://spacyr.quanteda.io. It looks like you have not properly installed **spacyr**.